# Codility programming test and Objective-C syntax

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, syntax

I've been looking at the Codility tests, (http://codility.com/) as I was thinking of trying to obtain a certificate, but I've come up against some very strange syntax errors, it's seems to use a slightly different version of Objective-C to iOS.

For example, the function to complete was declared as so:

`int equi (NSMutableArray *A) { //.... }`

as opposed to

`-(int)equi:(NSMutableArray *)A { //... }`

and when I declared the following `for` loop (`A` is an array of `NSNumber`):

```
12. for (int i = 0; i < [A count]; i++){
13.    total = total + [[A objectAtIndex:i] intValue];   
14. }
```

it gave me the following compile errors:

```
func.m:12: error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
func.m:12: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
func.m:13: error: invalid operands to binary + (have 'double' and 'id')
```

If anyone could shed any light on this, pre haps the version of objective-c or compiler version is different?

Thanks

**EDIT:** @Kos from Codility has commented below, they have recently switched their Objective-C compiler to Clang, which should mean most of the questions I'd asked are now non-issues.

Comment: If you don't even know C, how do you want to obtain a certificate for Objective-C? (Sorry state of software development...)

Comment: Codility here; we've switched the Obj-C compiler from GCC to Clang recently, so modern syntax and features are available now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note this question was strictly in the context of Codility, which does not explicitly tell you which version of C it is compiling against.

As H2CO3 pointed out, the declaration is a C-function. I was thrown because the test was supposed to be in Objective-C, not C, and while yes, Objective-C is a superset of C, I was expecting Objective-C syntax.

Codility does not give you access to compiler flags, hence why the stack trace was not useful. The problem was the initial declaration of `i` being inside the `for` loop declaration (C90 style). It should have be rewritten as this to be explicit:

```
int i = 0;
int count = [A count];
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    total = total + [((NSNumber *)[A objectAtIndex:i]) intValue];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int equi (NSMutableArray *A) { //.... }
```

This is not a 'different version of Objective-C'. This is a C function.

The compiler errors are generated because...

```
'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
```

And the compiler tells you the solution right one line later:

```
use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
```

The other one can be resolved by casting:

```
total = total + (int)[[A objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
```

or, even better:

```
total = total + [(NSNumber *)[A objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried taking the Objective-C test and had a similar experience. My conclusion is that Codility supports Objective-C 1 and not modern Objective-C 2. It looked to me like Codility uses the gcc compiler, which is why it's old Objective-C syntax. Those of us who work on the Apple platforms are accustomed to Apple's updated Objective-C 2. Unfortunately, I am not aware of any programming test for modern Objective-C.

Comment: Good insight, that was exactly the case. Now Clang is being used, so the features you'd expect should already be available. Feel free to [give it a try](https://codility.com/train/) :-)

Answer (score -2):

Inside the for loop, the count isn't correct. The correct count is the array count - 1, as follows:

```
int i = 0;
int contagem = [A count];
for (i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
    total = total + [((NSNumber *)A[i]) intValue];
}
```